# How to display "custom post" data according to "custom post" in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new in wordpress, I have two tables "wp_posts" and "wp_postmeta",Whenever admin Add "custom post type" then
in post data is inserting with "post_type"(project) like this

```
id          post_title        post_type         
1             abc               project
...
```

This data is showing in "subscribe/user" panel and And whenever user accept this request(post) then data is inserting in "wp_postmeta" table

```
meta_id        post_id                    meta_key              meta_value
1               1(project/post)           project_status          8(userId)
```

now i create another "custom post" so admin can check which user accept this request,now i just want to fetch data from "wp_postmeta" (according to "mea_key", fetching
data from db)

So how can we fetch data in "custom post field" (acording to condition) ?

Comment: If you are new to WordPress, I suggest avoiding thinking too much about the database itself (for now). Instead, think of WordPress as a whole the thing you are interacting with. For this specific case, look into [`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/). Also, most WordPress developers I know, myself included, use a helper plugin such as [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to help us manage fields.